# What's "Blumenthal" as an adjective (UK)

Tags: british-english

I'm an American reading a series of humorous kitchen-gadget reviews in The Guardian, and the author describes a particular food dehydrator as something that "makes you feel just a little bit Blumenthal".[1] Since it's a common last name, searching is mostly noise. I can't see anything about the top hits on Google or wikipedia for Blumenthals that make sense. Is there a Brit out there that can educate me?

[1] http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2015/jul/08/kitchen-gadgets-review-food-dehydrator (at heading "Why?")

Comment: This Yank would take "Blumenthal" to be the name of some person who has strong opinions that are somehow pertinent to food dehydrators.  It could be, eg, that "Blumenthal" is the name of a gardening writer who advocates preserving your own foods.  (Or it could be that he's an economist known for being stingy.)

Comment: [Heston Blumenthal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heston_Blumenthal)

Comment: @StoneyB - Yeah, Heston Blumenthal would fit my assumption fairly well.

Comment: Yes, Heston Blumenthal is famous for using serious technology in his cooking, including liquid nitrogen.  [Also for weird combos such as snail ice-cream, by the way.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heston Blumenthal, per comments. Just putting an answer so this shows up as answered in searches.